# multiple row update with php into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I am trying to update multiple rows here.However I fail to point the right ID of the row.

```
<?php
$table = 'DynamicPage';
$query = mysql_query(Query::SelectAllFrom($table));
// Count table rows 
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id[] = $row['ID'];
    echo '        
                    <h3>Column name: </h3><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" value="' . $row['Name'] . '" />

                    <h3>Tekst: </h3><textarea type="text" name="fulltext[]" maxlength="2000">' . $row['FullText'] . '</textarea>';
}
echo '<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                      </form>';
// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $queryUP = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET Name='" . $_POST['name'] . "' WHERE id='??????????????'");
        $result  = mysql_query($queryUP);
    }
    if ($result) {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
}
?>
```

So far I can update the first row (if id='1') from the last `<h3>Column name: </h3><input type="text" name="name"...`  I know that I am not passing the ID's in the right way, but I have to idea about the syntax. If anyone has an idea, please let me know :) 
Thanks

Comment: Your script right now is wide open to tampering (hacking) via SQL injection.  Surround query input vars  with `mysql_real_escape_string()`:  `SET Name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."' WHERE id...`

Comment: You'll need to describe your goal a little better. It is difficult to discern from your code what you're actually trying to accomplish here, and how the first query producing IDs relates to the second one.

Comment: I have to make simple admin panel, where I "select" all the columns from a certain table. Once the user makes a change, the "update" button should trigger the "update mysql query". So based on the ID of the row from the "select" query I have to update the rows. That is why I use this ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should add a hidden input field with IDs:

HTML part

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$row['ID'].'" />
<h3>Column name: </h3><input type="text" name="name[]" maxlength="30" value="'.$row['Name'].'" />
<h3>Tekst: </h3><textarea name="fulltext[]" maxlength="2000">'.$row['FullText'].'</textarea>';
```

PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['ID']); ++$i){
//query goes here
}
```

SQL QUERY

```
UPDATE $table SET Name='{$_POST['name'][$i]}', Tekst='{$_POST['fulltext'][$i]}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id'][$i]}'
```

This is from top off my head, not tested, but should give you an idea.
And of course, escape all the input fields.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion, unfortunately the data remains unchanged. The data is "inside" , but the query can't see the selected ID

Comment: Actually, it could be the case issue (ID vs. id). I've updated my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your `$_POST['Submit']` `isset` test:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($id);$i++) {
    $queryUP = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET Name='".$_POST['name']."' WHERE id = " . $id[$i]);
    $result = mysql_query($queryUP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input type="text" ids="id[]" maxlength="30" value="'.$row['id'].'"
//then submit part
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id'];$i++) {
$queryUP = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET Name='".$_POST['name']."' WHERE id='$_POST['id'][$i]'");
$result = mysql_query($queryUP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may concatenate $row['ID'] and $row['Name'] to create a name you can parse later

```
<h3>Column name: </h3><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" 
     value="' . $row['ID']  . '_' . $row['Name'] . '" />
```

then you can use something like:

```
list($name, $id) = explode($_POST['name'], '_');
```

** also note you have a security risk using user input directly inside SQL statement